# iOS: how to convert NSString to NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How would I convert this string `recentUpdate` to an `NSdate`? My `recentUpdate` outputs this 10/05/2014 06:43:PM and when a converted it to NSDate, it always results `null`.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Any tips or suggestions are appreciated. My question is a little more specific compare to the other questions on stackoverflow so this isn't a duplicate question.

```
NSString *recentUpdate = sharedData.mUser.mRecentUpdateTime;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateFromString:recentUpdate usingFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: you should take a look at NSDateFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format does not match the string you gave:

```
MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss
10/05/2014 06:43:PM
  ^  ^           ^^
  Here           and here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting any string to NSDate, make sure your string format should be same as the format you are passing in date-formatter.

Example - 
for string like `10/05/2014 06:43:PM`, your date format should be - `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:a`

for string like `10-05-2014 06:43 PM`, your date format should be - `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm a`

otherwise result will be `null` .